# Shift an NSOrderedSet circularly to another index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-category, circular-list

I am working on an application which works with items distributed in a circular route.
The entry point is random.

So when the whole thing starts I need to shift the set with all the positions to a random index.

**Example** (with arbitrary data):

```
0:Hungry -> 1:Eating -> 2:Full -> 3:Vomiting*
```

If I shift this to the index `2` I get the following new set.

```
2:Full -> 3:Vomiting -> 0:Hungry -> 1:Eating
```

So how to achieve this in Objective C?

<sub>`*` Sorry, but I needed another element because three elements didn't seem to get the point across...</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with a category on `NSOrderedSet`:

```
NSOrderedSet *newSet = [initialSet orderedSetByShiftingToIndex:2];
```

This is my Category on `NSOrderedSet`:

```
@implementation NSOrderedSet(Shifting)

-(NSOrderedSet *)orderedSetByShiftingToIndex:(int)newIndex{

    if(newIndex == 0 || newIndex > self.count -1){
        return self;
    }

    NSMutableOrderedSet *result = [self mutableCopy];
    NSIndexSet *moveToEnd = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, newIndex -1)];

    int endIndex = result.count-1;

    [result moveObjectsAtIndexes:moveToEnd toIndex:endIndex];

    return result;
}

@end
```